# Add a remote Archetype Catalog in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

I am new to IntelliJ but coming from Eclipse I expected Maven support to be far better. It really is but I could not find how to define a remote archetype catalog in IntelliJ (14.1).

All I could find was a way to add a Archetype manually but that is not what I need. I would like to point to a XML file on a remote server that contains the list of all archetypes available.

In Eclipse, it looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Maybe you would like to try an Intellij Plugin that I wrote yesterday. It enables you to add remote archetype catalogs to Idea: [Maven Archetype Catalog plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965?pr=idea)

To make my answer more clear: I had the same issue that it struggles me that you can add Maven Archetype Catalog files in Eclipse, but not in IntelliJ IDEA. So I tried to write a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, so that you can actually define URLs to archetype-catalog.xml.

The plugin just parses those URLs and provides the Maven Archetypes to the list of available Archetypes in IntelliJ IDEA.

After installing the Plugin you can find a new entry in the Settings menu at File - Settings - Build, Execution and Deployment - Build tools.

Comment: I suggest explaining more about the plugin, rather than just promoting your product. If it were not relevant, this answer would be considered spam otherwise

Comment: It is a shame this is minus'ed as down as much as it is, because this does exactly what I think the original asker wants. I stumbled across this question looking for the same solution. I can state that it is working for me as you would expect it to work in eclipse equivalently. You get a +1 from me.

Comment: I confirm this works exactly as I asked at least version 1.0.4. My previous attempt (pre-1.0.0 releases) were not as successful. Thanks for the hard work Dominik !

Comment: I am not able to see File -> Settings in mac Intellj. I am missing something very basic?

Comment: got it under preferences.. thanks (yes i was missing the basics :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is kinda old thread, but in the future if some one will look for it.

This [Maven Archetype Catalogs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965?pr=idea) is a plugin for intellij that allows import external archetypes from a URL.
It solved my problem on Linux, haven't tried it on Windows.

To add this plugin go to File->Settings->Plugins->Browse repositories
in the search bar type "Maven Archetype Catalogs". Install and restart.

To use it go to File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven Archetype Catalogs. click the '+' and add the archetype-catalog

Comment: At least give a summary of the program, and its features! :-)

Comment: I see what your saying but if you read the question it's pretty clear what this plugin for intellij does. will edit.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a plugin to do this - [Maven Archetypes](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1789?pr=). The reviews are not favourable, and I have never used it though so cannot comment to its effectiveness.

You could also (assuming Windows/IntelliJ 14), edit `C:\Users\<username>\.IntelliJIdea14\system\Maven\Indices\UserArchetypes.xml` and add the archetypes manually. Not ideal, but still workable.

Comment: thanks you for your answer, but this old plugin seems equivalent to the actual maven support in IntelliJ. From what I see in only works with local catalogs, same of the `.IntelliJIdea14\system\Maven\Indices\UserArchetypes.xml` file.
I am looking for a solution to use remote catalogs.

Answer (score -1):

Screenshots are made in IDEA 14, I've also checked IDEA 13, it's also true for it.

If this is what you need
[image]

Then it's in the Preferences:
[image]

Comment: I will give it a try but this seems to be an option to add repositories not remote archetype catalogs. The Archetype catalog is really useful to create new projects based on a template which is updated frequently, in my case, by someone of the company. More about archetype catalogs : http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/specification/archetype-catalog.html

Comment: Yes, I see. Used this feature yesterday. Adding a catalogue to this list did not help.

Comment: Why do I only see "Importing", "Ignored Files", "Running" under Maven? IntelliJ V14.1.3

Comment: @weston probably because you have no open project. Open or start one and the two extra tabs will appear. Have no idea, what's the logic of that, maybe they contain settings for a particular project.